# iTextSharp: align image and text

Tags: image, alignment, itext

I am using iTextSharp to export reports in PDF format. Reports' headers should have following format:
[image]

The problem is to align report header by center of the page, while there is an image on the left of the page. When I use a table, report header is aligned by center of its cell, not by center of the page. Is there a better approach?

**EDIT:**
Code for adding header is following:

```
var doc = new Document(pageSize, margins.Width, margins.Width, margins.Height, margins.Height);
using (PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, destination))
{
    doc.Open();
    var headerTable = new PdfPTable(1){ WidthPercentage = 100 };
    RenderHeader(headerTable); // adds several lines to headerTable
    doc.Add(headerTable);
}
```

Comment: How are you adding the header? If you're using page events (which is the preferred method), you can put the text wherever you want using `ColumnText.ShowTextAligned();`

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I updated my question with code

Comment: That's not how you add a header, is it? Or are we talking about two different things? I'm talking about a header as in "headers and footers". Seems like you're talking about a header you only use once...

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Yes, it's a header that appears only at the beginnig of the document (not on every page).

Comment: OK, sorry, I misunderstood. There are different ways to achieve what you want, let me think about the best way. I'll answer later;

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a `PdfPTable`?

Why not add a `Paragraph` with the data that is right-aligned, followed by a couple of `Paragraph`s that are centered.

Then add the image at an absolute position, for instance:

```
Image img = Image.GetInstance(path_to_image);
img.SetAbsolutePosition(36, PdfWriter.getVerticalPosition(true));
document.Add(Image);
```

Another option is to add the `Image` in a table or a cell event instead of adding it straight to the table. Suppose that your `PdfPTable` consists of a single row and a single column, then you could define a cell event like this:

```
public class ImageCell : IPdfPCellEvent {
    public void CellLayout(
        PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position, PdfContentByte[] canvases
    ) {
        float x1 = position.Left + 2;
        float y1 = position.Top - 2;
        float y2 = position.Bottom + 2;
        PdfContentByte canvas = canvases[PdfPTable.LINECANVAS];
        Image img = Image.GetInstance(path_to_image);
        img.scaleToFit(10000, y1 - y2);
        img.SetAbsolutePosition(x1, y2);
        canvas.AddImage(img);
    }
}
```

Suppose that cell is the PdfPCell with the date and the title, then you can do this:

```
cell.CellEvent = new ImageCell();
```

Note that in this case, the image will be scaled to the height of the cell.

Forgive me if the code doesn't compile right away, I'm writing this by heart (based on experience), I didn't test the actual code.